# SSD no longer recognized after attempted Ubuntu installation

Tags: ssd, uefi, sata

I have attempted to install a dual boot of Linux (and my existing windows 10), but since the last attempt, one of the hard drive has disappeared.

The original setup was two drives, the first of which was a [Seagate Barracuda 2 TB](https://www.seagate.com/internal-hard-drives/hdd/barracuda/), on which the Windows 10 partition is, and, as far as I can tell, the other is a [Samsung Solid State Drive 2TB](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/memory-storage/solid-state-drives/ssd-860-evo-2-5--sata-iii-2tb-mz-76e2t0b-am/).

I have attempted to install Linux a few times (from a USB bootable iso of ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64) on that second drive, with various problems, but until now nothing too tragic happened and I could simply format it again to re-attempt it. On the last attempt, using a manual partition for the installation on this drive (with the various partitions recommended [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation/343352#343352)), upon rebooting after installing it, I got this error :

[image]

It's an error I had previously, I think, so I didn't think too much of it, but ever since, that ssd has completely disappeared. It doesn't show up on Windows 10's Disk Management anymore, nor the device manager, or third party softwares like EasyUS. It does not show up on the list of bootable peripherals for the UEFI either, and, from what I can remember, it was the SATA0 device, which now shows nothing :

[image]

I checked the cables, attempted to unplug and replug them just in case, but no change. I thought about maybe switching the SATA cables of the two drives, but I'm a bit scared that this could be a bad idea.

What happened to this drive, did the botched installation somehow fry it? And can I do anything to salvage it?

Edit : Switching the drive to a different SATA port did not help, alas.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like the disk is dead. It's not your fault - nothing you did is a low-level operation. You were just writing and reading bytes, that's what disks are supposed to do with no issues for years. Get it replaced if you can.

Comment: Did this happen for any specific reason and can it be avoided if so? I'd rather not buy a new disk to have it bricked again.

Comment: As I said, it doesn't look like it was your fault - just a faulty drive. It should be covered by warranty.